# Vangrant on Windows 10 with Hyper-V cannot mount SMB shared folder

Tags: vagrant, window, homestead, hyper-v, samba

## Problem

I'm struggling to have vagrant mounting shared folders via SMB.

## Environment

Windows 10 Pro with Hyper-V and SMB features enabled
Vagrant 2.2.6 with `vagrant-vbguest` (0.21.0, global) plugin

### Homestead.yaml file

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: hyperv

authorize: c:/Users/sgrat/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - c:/Users/sgrat/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: Sites/mysite
      to: /home/vagrant/mysite
      php: '7.3'
      type: "smb"
      smb_host: 127.0.0.1
      smb_username: vagrant
      smb_password: vagrant

sites:
    - map: mysite.test
      to: /home/vagrant/mysite

databases:
    - mysitedb

features:
    - mariadb: true
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false
```

## Error

```
Vagrant requires administrator access to create SMB shares and
may request access to complete setup of configured shares.
==> homestead: Setting hostname...
==> homestead: Mounting SMB shared folders...
    homestead: C:/Users/sgrat/Desktop/Sites/Homestead => /vagrant
Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because
the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly. The command attempted was:

mount -t cifs -o vers=2.0,credentials=/etc/smb_creds_vgt-4a666e6cffbb30e1d0bc7bb643cb3aee-6ad5fdbcbf2eaa93bd62f92333a2e6e5,uid=1000,gid=1000 //192.168.1.14/vgt-4a666e6cffbb30e1d0bc7bb643cb3aee-6ad5fdbcbf2eaa93bd62f92333a2e6e5 /vagrant

The error output from the last command was:

mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

## Additional attempts

I also installed `vboxsf` fs on guest machine after `vagrant ssh` with `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11` and even checked for last `cifs-utils` version.

I even created a local/admin user with name/password `vagrant` and granted all privilages on both "Sites" folder and "Sites" shared folder.

## Update #1

Shared "Sites" folder on Windows host, so updated homestead shared folder path to start from that instead from C: drive.
Is it correct?

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this, as I have the same issue.

Comment: here is the [very detail step-by-step guide](https://blog.devgenius.io/speed-up-laravel-8-homestead-with-hyper-v-step-by-step-guide-99505199d003), in order to make the share work properly, you need to set the folder permission and VM obtained the same subnet IP to access the SMB share.